# LESS files not getting compiled

Tags: node.js, less

Below is a snippet from my node.js file
I am trying to compile code from LESS into CSS.
Am I missing anything

```
app.use(lessMiddleware({
    src: path.join(__dirname, '/public/stylesheets/styles', 'less'), 
    dest: path.join(__dirname, '/public/stylesheets/css'),
    prefix : '/stylesheets',
}));
```

When I refresh my index.html, it throws me below error

```
TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings
    at f (path.js:204:15)
    at Object.filter (native)
    at Object.exports.join (path.js:209:40)
    at C:\SrkOwnRepo\Hotaaal\HotelUI10892515\node_modules\less-middleware\lib\mi
ddleware.js:161:27
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\SrkOwnRepo\Hotaaal\HotelUI10892515\n
ode_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\SrkOwnRepo\Hotaaal\HotelUI10892515\node_modules\express\l
ib\router\index.js:312:13)
    at C:\SrkOwnRepo\Hotaaal\HotelUI10892515\node_modules\express\lib\router\ind
ex.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\SrkOwnRepo\Hotaaal\HotelUI10892515\node_modul
es\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
    at next (C:\SrkOwnRepo\Hotaaal\HotelUI10892515\node_modules\express\lib\rout
er\index.js:271:10)
    at expressInit (C:\SrkOwnRepo\Hotaaal\HotelUI10892515\node_modules\express\l
ib\middleware\init.js:33:5)
TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings
    at f (path.js:204:15)
    at Object.filter (native)
    at Object.exports.join (path.js:209:40)
    at C:\SrkOwnRepo\Hotaaal\HotelUI10892515\node_modules\less-middleware\lib\mi
ddleware.js:161:27
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\SrkOwnRepo\Hotaaal\HotelUI10892515\n
ode_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\SrkOwnRepo\Hotaaal\HotelUI10892515\node_modules\express\l
ib\router\index.js:312:13)
    at C:\SrkOwnRepo\Hotaaal\HotelUI10892515\node_modules\express\lib\router\ind
ex.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\SrkOwnRepo\Hotaaal\HotelUI10892515\node_modul
es\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
    at next (C:\SrkOwnRepo\Hotaaal\HotelUI10892515\node_modules\express\lib\rout
er\index.js:271:10)
    at expressInit (C:\SrkOwnRepo\Hotaaal\HotelUI10892515\node_modules\express\l
ib\middleware\init.js:33:5)
```

Please provide a workaround or any other middleware.

Answer (score 0):

The [less-middleware function](https://github.com/emberfeather/less.js-middleware/blob/b4f18d634fd342c3015873613cefa62a485149dc/lib/middleware.js#L90) has a different interface than the one you showed in the code snippet.

It looks like this `lessMiddleware(source, options)`, where `source` is a string and `options` is an object. And it breaks somewhere around [here](https://github.com/emberfeather/less.js-middleware/blob/b4f18d634fd342c3015873613cefa62a485149dc/lib/middleware.js#161) when it tries to to call `path.join` on `source`, in your case an object.

You can check out the [documentation of the middleware](https://github.com/emberfeather/less.js-middleware#express) for the accepted parameters in options.